# Обработка get запроса python

Tags: python, http, get

есть сервер

```
# from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer # python2
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer # python3
class HandleRequests(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write("received get request")

    def do_POST(self):
        '''Reads post request body'''
        self._set_headers()
        content_len = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length', 0))
        post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
        print (post_body)
        self.wfile.write("received post request:<br>{}".format(post_body))

    def do_PUT(self):
        self.do_POST()

host = ''
port = 80
HTTPServer((host, port), HandleRequests).serve_forever()
```

Пост тут обрабатывается, а вот как сделать что бы была обработка get запроса. Допустим мне приходит url [http://домен/profile.php?id=12345678](http://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD/profile.php?id=12345678)
а в ответ мой сервер выводит в консоли id=12345678 как это делает print (post_body)

переделал

```
    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        o = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path) 
        print (urllib.parse.parse_qs(o.query))
```

в ответ приходит

```
192.168.250.17 - - [19/Feb/2020 15:16:47] "GET /?data:asdad HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{}
```

Comment: Доступ к параметрам url строки получить надо что ли? Если да, то примерно как то так:  `import urlparse                   
o = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)                  
urlparse.parse_qs(o.query)             `

Comment: Да именно это мне и нужно, только у меня питон3 и надо делать через urllib.parse